# How to define a method in Laravel Model and access Eloquent methods?

Tags: php, laravel-4

MY model code is given below. All I want to find a record by Id and update a field. Instead of updating it's creating a new record:

```
  class Item extends \Eloquent
  {
    protected $fillable = [];

    function subscribe()
    {
        $item = $this->find(array('id' => 1));
        $item->waiting = 4000;
        $t =  $this->save();
        print("We call u\n");
        print_r($t);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do - but this might work

```
function subscribe()
    {
        $this->find(1);
        $this->waiting = 4000;
        $this->save();
        print("We call u\n");
        print_r($this->toArray());
    }
```

Comment: `$this->find(1)` won't set `$this` to the model with id 1. So this will likely create a new record as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to actually `save()` the `$item` and not `$this`:

```
function subscribe()
{
    $item = $this->find(array('id' => 1));
    $item->waiting = 4000;
    $t =  $item->save();
    print("We call u\n");
    print_r($t);
}
```